# Готовая CMS или сайт с нуля?

Tags: php, интернет-магазин

Скажите что лучше? 
Разработать с нуля самому интернет-магазин или использовать готовую CMS?

Плюсы, минусы опишите.

Comment: Это вопрос наподобие "мне купить торт или самому испечь?". Использовать готовую легче, если ваши требования стандартные.

Comment: На подобный вопрос, я когда уже отвечал, но повторюсь, слегка перефразировав: "Если вам уровень логики не позволяет ответить на свой же, простой вопрос, то лучше, поникнув головой выбрать скорбную дорогу на Ucoz" ;)

Comment: @VladD немного не точное сравнение. Тут лучше подойдет: "мне купить машину или самому её сделать?" :) Чес. слово - берите готовую и уже готовую кмс пилите.

Comment: @lampa: программисты известны своей любовью к изобретению велосипедов, зачастую очень даже неплохих. :) Ну и вдруг ТСу нужна не машина, а поезд? Хотя если вопрос возникает...

Comment: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4954528/
Кто-нибудь читал?
Хорошая книга?

Компании, предлагающие интернет-магазин под заказ, используют готовые CMS?

Comment: Вы хотите продавать магазины?)

Книгу не читал, но по-любому - покажет только верхушку айсберга.

Если знания позволяют - можно сделать без всяких книжек. Если не позволяют - то и с книжками ни фига не сделаете. Но expierence свой повысите.

Так что читайте - лишним не будет.

Comment: Компании, предлагающие интернет-магазин под заказ, используют готовые CMS?

Comment: @Радик Камалов в 99% случаях :) У них либо свои, либо допиленные чужие, либо просто чужие.

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не стоит**, я сам пишу CMS второй месяц, проблем много, много что переписывать, минимум месяц - это если дизайн будет, на отладку времени много уйдет, самое страшное, что со мной щас случилось это мысль о том, что архитектуру CMS мне нужно щас заново переписывать, а это почти всё в  топку!

Comment: > архитектуру CMS мне нужно щас заново
> переписывать

Это неизбежно)

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос стоит такой

> Готовая CMS или сайт с нуля?

Тогда готовая CMS.

Тут без вариантов.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть сомнения в этом вопросе, то лучше берите готовый скрипт. Потому как для создания магазина с нуля (и чтобы оно потом не глючило и не было дырявым со всех сторон) нужно проделать очень большую работу, и обладать при этом соответствующей квалификацией.

Comment: Хотел выбрать "Интернет-магазин" как тему диплома. 
в разработке еще 3 месяца.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, для таких случаев есть "стандартное" решение )) Если вам нужно всего лишь стандартные функции - CMS. А если вам нужно что-то уникальное - фреймворки.

Answer (score -1):

Почему,без вариантов,я бы все с нуля написал,ты знаешь ,что и ,где находится)плюс большой опыт,сам магазин написал,круто!!!))
Ну а если надо по-быстрому ,то берите смс,я бы сам написал)
Плюс,когда сам пишешь можно фишек добавить)

Comment: 1 минус - это тестирование
2 безопасность кода 
и перечислять можно долго и упорно.

Так что тут без вариантов - только готовое решение!

Ответ, на мой взгляд начинающего разработчика. "Сам бы написал".

Перечисленные плюсы появятся через пару лет когда придет опыт и понимание.

Comment: если у товарища есть уйма свободного времени! и опыт года 3, то вполне можно)

Comment: Ну это и имеется ввиду.

Comment: У популярных CMS есть явное преимущество - безопасность. Ими явно не в одиночку занимаются, а группы людей. Причем людей не первый год в этом деле. Конечно есть исключения, но эти дыры проще пофиксить, нежели самому писать сайт.
Хотя согласен, что в готовых CMS порой очень много лишних и не нужных модулей.